# create multiple file with content in linux with user input

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I'm new in bash scripting and I'm trying to create a bash script which can create multiple file with content (around 10000 lines [no matters what text]) but with user input.
I made a script which create files (see below) but how can I fill each file with 10000 lines?
Thank you in advance!

```
#!/bin/bash
echo How many files do you want to create?
read numberOfFiles
echo
echo Please enter the files name with should start:
read nameForFiles
echo

for i in $(seq 1 $numberOfFiles)
do
        touch $nameForFiles-$i.txt
done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your `touch` command with this:

```
for ((j=0; j<9999; j++)); do echo "Cyrus was here"; done > "$nameForFiles-$i.txt"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

read -rp "How many files do you want to create? " numberOfFiles
echo
read -rp "Please enter the file name: " nameForFiles
echo

for ((n=1;n<=numberOfFiles;n++)); do
    for i in {1..1000}; do
        echo "line $i" >> "${nameForFiles}"-"${n}".txt
    done
done
```

Comment: `for ((i=1; i<=1000; i++))` would be preferable over having to expand `{1..1000}` into a list of 1000 numbers before iteration begins.

Comment: thank you too for answer!